# Flutter: Navigator.pushReplacement / pushAndRemoveUntil kill animations

Tags: navigation, dart, flutter

I'm wondering if Is there a way of using a Navigator call that doesn't allow the user to navigate back and keeps the Hero Widget's animations intact? I have a hero widget image transition between a Splash and Login screens but I want to keep user from navigating back from the splash. Both Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil and Navigator.pushReplacement kill animations transition animation.

Comment: I'm running into this same situation, Hero animation doesn't seem to work when using `pushReplacement`, did you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

My solution, created mostly because WillPopScope pollutes another page and blocks hardware button on Android which should close the app:

```
  Future<void> pushAndReplace(String routeName) async {
    final current = ModalRoute.of(context);
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/login');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1));
    Navigator.removeRoute(context, current);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap a widget with a `WillPopScope`, and then always return `false` on the `onWillPop` attribute, to prevent it from ever navigating back. Eg;

`return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => Future.value(false),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Container()
      ...
)`

Answer (score 0):

Any time you use `Navigator.xxxx` you are changing to a completely new view. I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure animations need to be contained in a single view and do not carry between views.

You may want to look into using **States** to handle this. I use [flutter_redux](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_redux) for managing state in my flutter application. It is best suited for larger apps that have complex states to wrangle. For simple state management you can use Flutter's built in state capabilities. [They have an interactivity tutorial here](https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/).